# Automatic merging of Dependabot generated Pull Request with codeowners file and branch protection rule?

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot, github-codeowners

I have created Workflow for GitHub Actions as described here: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/automating-dependabot-with-github-actions

```yaml
    name: Dependabot auto-approve
    on: pull_request_target
    
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write
    
    jobs:
      dependabot:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        if: ${{ github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]' }}
        steps:

          - name: Approve a PR
            run: gh pr review --approve "$PR_URL"
            env:
              PR_URL: ${{github.event.pull_request.html_url}}
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}

          - name: Enable auto-merge for Dependabot PRs
            run: gh pr merge --auto --merge "$PR_URL"
            env:
              PR_URL: ${{github.event.pull_request.html_url}}
              # The documentation incorrectly forgets `GITHUB_TOKEN` here.
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

Above automation works, but I have a Branch protection rule that requires review from the Code Owners.

Is there a way to include `github-actions` to the CODEOWNERS file in order to make its approval counted?

Comment: Is the behavior the same using a `PAT` from a codeowner account instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of right now, a GitHub app cannot be added to CODEOWNERS as quoted [here](https://github.community/t/is-it-possible-to-add-github-apps-bot-to-codeowners/3146/2).

> Thank you for being here! Currently, GitHub Apps can’t be used in CODEOWNERS – that’s not supported. It’s something the team is considering for the future, and I’ll be sure to add your use case to the internal feature request.

However, what you can do, is to use a GitHub personal access token generated by yourself as explained [in the documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), then add it as a secret and use it in your workflow. See the [GitHub Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow) .

The last step of your action would then reference your self-defined secret. In the below example, I assume it's called `MYTOKEN`

```
          - name: Enable auto-merge for Dependabot PRs
            run: gh pr merge --auto --merge "$PR_URL"
            env:
              PR_URL: ${{github.event.pull_request.html_url}}
              # The documentation incorrectly forgets `GITHUB_TOKEN` here.
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.MYTOKEN}}
```

With this approach, a merge would be done as your user, who is - I assume - part of the CODEOWNERS.